# Git revert failed

Tags: git, git-commit, git-revert

I made several commits (commit1/2/3), I changed my working directory without stashing. Then I wanted to go back several commits ago. So I git revert commit1 commit2 commit3, but I was told to commit my changes (commit4), so I did it, and then I made again git revert commit1 commit2 commit3 commit4, but I had a message

> error: a cherry-pick or revert is already in progress  hint: try "git
> cherry-pick (--continue | --quit | --abort)"

When I run git branch -va, HEAD is pointing to commit 3.

I don't quite understand what is going on.  What should I do now to make things reverted?

Comment: I hate git so much.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is best to initiate a revert with a clean index and working tree.
Otherwise, doing a second revert (on top of a new commit) while a previous revert was in progress leads to that error message.

Since you are still at `commit 3`, you could:

- `git cherry-pick --quit` (which, from [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/185716), tells revert to leave `HEAD` alone and get out of the way.),
- examine your index and working tree (git status),
- make any adjustment to get a clean status (like a new commit),
- and then re-do your `git revert`.

(you can see other options at "[Rollback to Previous Commit - Github for MAC (a revert is already in progress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858416/rollback-to-previous-commit-github-for-mac-a-revert-is-already-in-progress)")

Don't forget [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html) if you simply want to forget about those three commits (although that would make you force a push: `git push --force`, in order to publish your history for that branch. If other collaborators already pulled from that same branch, your approach, using `git revert`, is a better one)